# How can I autogenerate Code128 in Adobe Forms once I have the font?

Tags: forms, adobe, barcode, code128, adobe-form

I am trying to get Adobe Form to autogenerate a Code128 in a text field by its self when text is input in another text field. I know there is Code128 font, and I have found a bunch of postscript stuff. I am just wondering IF I have to purchase the font and why? (I see something about the license) I just worry I spend this money on a Coding font and I still can't do what I'm wanting by "changing the font" for the "barcode" text field. I don't know any coding, closest is I took an HTML web design class in high school YEARS ago. I appreciate any help. Just to show the one line of code I found (gosh I don't even have a clue HOW) is

'''event.value = this.getField("Size In HP").value;'''

I don't even know if I am using it in the proper "script" box option in Adobe, I just place it and change it to what box I want. hoping it works. -_- (side note the ''' are around the code because below this typing window it shows to do that?)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not planning on a separate program for calculating the checksum, you should stay away from Code128, as the font won't generate the checksum for you. Code39 does not require a checksum, therefore, no calculation.

As long as all you need is capital letters and numbers, Code39 is much easier to work with.